# How to find total size of all versions of a file in git?

Tags: git

I have a large git repository and I'm wondering what's using more space. There are a few binary files that could be automatically generated from source. They're not big but change pretty often. How can I understand the total space these files use over time? Assume their path never changes.

Comment: Git uses [Objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) internally. Every change saves the whole file (`blob`). Git then uses a `zlib` compression which saves you some space.

Answer (score 1):

Analyzing the exact impact of a single file can be tricky since all objects are compressed together, so better use a dedicated tool.

Consider using [git-sizer](https://github.com/github/git-sizer/#getting-started) to analyze your repository. It helps you by highlighting the parts of your repository that are more problematic.

Comment: thank you, I'm already using it but it's not helping with this job